# conflicts with the registered path with cxf

Tags: jetty, apache-camel, cxf

We are starting multiple web service endpoints with same base name using code below. For instance, http://localhost:9001/org/dep and http://localhost:9001/org/dep/manage . It used to work till 2.1.7. After we upgraded CXF to 3.1.4 and it is failing with below exception .

I am working with cxf 3.1.4 and jetty 9.3.4.v20151007

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not add cxf jetty handler for url http://localhost:8585/rs/jde/jxml to Jetty server, as the path /rs/jde/jxml is still in use.
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.checkRegistedContext(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:317)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:386)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:175)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:53)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBindingFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSBindingFactory.addListener(JAXRSBindingFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:206)
```

Comment: Tell exactly what the before and after versions of CXF and Camel are.

Comment: Thanks for reply .Before we were using camel 2.10.0 fuse-71-047 now we are upgrading that to  2.15.1.And cxf  was 2.7X. we were working good with camel 2.15.1 and cxf 3.0.4 with cxf-bundle(3.0.0-milestone1)dependency but we don't want to use that dependency any more that making some version conflicts. Instead we are using all the other dependencies as mentioned in Red Hat JBoss Fuse 6.2 Migration Guide. Now we are at this point facing this issue. Please give some idea how can we solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Use the Red Hat Customer Portal to get commercial help with the product.